# How to format a number in a ruby on rails controller, number_with_delimiter works only in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to format a number in a controller before inserting it into a string. But the function number_with_delimiter() does not work in a controller.
I need the string to send to a javascript plugin.

I could run the code in the view, but I guess that is not the best option.

```
@mycarousel_itemList = @mycarousel_itemList + "{url: '" + p.photo.url(:thumb) + 
"', price: '" + p.price.to_s + "&nbsp;&euro;'},"
```

Is there an alternative function to change the format of p.price?

Comment: You can refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467697/rails-why-the-number-with-delimiter-method-is-not-recognized-inside-my-model/25979370#25979370

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To answer your question directly, include the following in your controller (typically near the top, below the `class` declaration):

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

You could also include this module in the model (whatever class `p` is), and then write a function to return the formatted price.

The best place for code like this, however, is in a helper, not the controller. The helper would be called from the view. Your controller should be as short as possible and not include any view logic at all.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.. great advice! I'll indeed move it to a helper.

Answer (score 20):

Just call the underlying `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper` method directly:

```
> ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(100000)
=> "100,000"
```

This avoids including all of the ActionView methods in your object unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

Rails controllers have access the same context that the ActionView renderer does using the `view_context` property without having to mixin multiple view helper modules:

```rb
class BaseController < ApplicationController                                                                                                      
  def index
    # Accessing view the context
    logger.info view_context.number_to_currency(34)
  end
end
```

This has the advantage to having complete access to all view helpers as well as any special configuration you may have setup (i.e., i18n settings).