# Rails: Why is the "number_with_delimiter" method not recognized inside my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, number-with-delimiter

I have a simple validation:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  ...
  validates_numericality_of :price, :less_than => 1000000, 
                            :message => "must be less than #{number_with_delimiter(1000000)}"                       
  ...
end
```

On this code, I have received the following error:

```
undefined method `number_with_delimiter' for #<Class:0x2665a58>
```

I tried to add:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The true problem here is that you're including this module into the class, rather than extended the class with it.

The differences is an include will make the methods available on the instance, where as the extend will make them where you're trying to use them: on the class.

For instance method use

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

For class method use

```
extend ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

Comment: @Ryan: I understand that including inside the class is equivalent to defining my own methods in this class, right ? Does this means that I could use `self.number_with_delimiter(...)` ? When you put the `include` outside the class, are all methods inside `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` becomes global ?

Comment: @Misha: Yes they'd become global but that's generally Not A Good Idea(tm). Best thing to do in this case is to `extend` the class with the module.

Comment: @Ryan: How do I extend the `Product` class with the `NumberHelper` module ? Isn't this what I did above ?

Comment: @Misha: No, you're `include`'ing the module. `extend` is different.

Comment: @Ryan: I'm confused. Including the module in model's class is exactly what I did above, and it didn't work. It worked, however, when I moved the `include` outside the class.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of extending `ActionView` module. You can use methods from `ActiveSupport` instead

For example:

`ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::number_to_currency(10000.1234,{precision: 2,unit: ''})`

Comment: is that better from a performance standpoint in terms of memory usage?

Answer (score 3):

You should use extend:

Usage: `extend ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`

It is good for me

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the dependency... is the NumberHelper class accessible to your application?

Check the [official Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

Answer (score 2):

good answer, use :

> ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::number_to_delimited(number, options={})