# Including modules and classes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time including some view helpers in a file thats in `/lib`, say I have this:

```
module TwitterPost
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def update
    number_with_delimiter(1234567)
  end
end
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `number_with_delimiter' for TwitterPost:Module
```

But in my console, I'm able to just `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` and then I'm able to just do `number_with_delimiter(1234567)` and it works just fine.

Why is this? I need to include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in a bunch of different models as well but I've had no luck in getting it to work.

Comment: You can refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467697/rails-why-the-number-with-delimiter-method-is-not-recognized-inside-my-model/25979370#25979370

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up how [Modules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html) work.

You need to mix the module into a class for the instance methods to work.

```
module TwitterPost
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def update
    number_with_delimiter(1234567)
  end
end

class Foo
  include TwitterPost
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.update
   => "1,234,567"
```