# Rails: Unable to include module in Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've defined a module in a file directly in my app folder, but am unable to use its methods in an ActiveRecord class (methods not recognized). As I understand it, files in the app folder are supposed to be required automatically by rails.

I've also tried to include it manually:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Curation
    ...
end
```

but I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Picture::Curation
```

Am I mistaken about this, and actually do need to manually require all new files?

Comment: Check this post , that could help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011624/including-modules-and-classes-in-rails

Comment: It would be helpful it you show the code for Curation module and what's the path/file_name of the file you put it.

Comment: @TanguyS in that question, the dev is trying to include inside a module

Comment: @PiotrJakubowski the filepath for the Curation module is app/gallery_curation.rb.

Curation code is just of the form:

module Curation
    
    def method1
        ....
    end
    ....
end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails does not require all the files from app in development mode. Instead it loads the files on demand when you reference the constant that is undefined. Then it guesses the filename from the name of the Class or Module. In your case you have a `Curation` module defined in `gallery_curation` file. When Rails notices `Curation` module that is undefined it is looking for `curation.rb` file in all subdirectories of `app`. Obviously the file can't be found, hence the exception.

You have 3 choices:

1. go with Rails' convention and either rename your file to `curation` or rename the module to `GalleryCuration`
2. go with custom require_dependency
3. set up an autoload path for `Curation` somewhere in your initializers.

For your sanity, going with convention is recommended.

More info about Rails autoloading here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Thank you, I did opt for the first one. Unfortunately, I still can't call the methods of the module

Comment: @user1618840 what do you mean you can't call methods of the module? I guess I need concrete example.

Comment: In the console: Curation.method_defined?(:curate_gallery)
 => true

Comment: Curation.curate_gallery =>
NoMethodError: undefined method `curate_gallery' for Curation:Module

Comment: When you include a module to the class then the methods of the module are instance_methods of the class. Which means that you can do `Picture.new.curate_gallery` and not `Curation.curate_gallery` or `Picture.curate_gallery`.

Comment: Ah I see thank you! So I think what I need to do is make them all class methods, eg self.curate_gallery

Comment: @user1618840 or you can use extend instead of include.

Answer (score 3):

Rails doesn't autoload from the `app` directory itself. If it's a module that is used in models only you could put it in the `app/models` directory (it doesn't matter that it's not actually a model). Alternatively if it is used in different types of classes you may be better putting it in `lib`.

Additionally, rails autoloading only works when rails can correctly guess the name of the file that the constant (module in this case) will be included in.

This means that you'll need to call your file `curation.rb` for rails to autoload the `Curation` module from it.

Comment: I tried putting it it in app/models, with the same result

Comment: You'll need to provide a few more details of the contents of your app/models/curation.rb file then.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the new information about the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks, this helps in that it now seems to include the module. Unfortunately I still can't call any of its methods